# Why is vuetable not registering <vuetable-field-slot:actions> when using __slot

Tags: vue.js

I am using [vuetable-2](https://www.vuetable.com/) in my project. It works fine until when I want to add action buttons at the end of every row. It displays the error:

```
<vuetable-field-slot:actions> - did you register the component correctly?
```

[image: image shows error that pops up when i use __slot to add custom action buttons at the end of each row in of the vuetable]

I don't know how I can go around this.

The fields of my vuetable look like this:

```js
data() {
    return {
        /* */
        fields: ['name', 'description', 'active',
            {
                name: '__slot:actions',
                title: 'Actions',
                titleClass: 'center aligned',
                dataClass: 'center aligned'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then `MyVuetable.vue` slot template:

```html
<vuetable ref="vuetable"
  /* */
>
  <template slot="actions" slot-scope="props">
    <div class="custom-actions">
      <button class="ui basic button"
        @click="onAction('view-item', props.rowData, props.rowIndex)">
        <i class="zoom icon"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="ui basic button"
        @click="onAction('edit-item', props.rowData, props.rowIndex)">
        <i class="edit icon"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="ui basic button"
        @click="onAction('delete-item', props.rowData, props.rowIndex)">
        <i class="delete icon"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </template>
</vuetable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the relevant documentation is here:

https://www.vuetable.com/guide/fields-definition.html#field-options

I'm not sure where you got the `name: '__slot:actions'` part from but the documentation indicates that any field name starting with `__` will be treated as a component name.

To use a slot you should just need `name: 'actions'`, matching the name of the slot in your template.